# Не выводится ViewPager

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь вывести ViewPager в layout. 
Пишу вот такой код

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); 
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Файл activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Приложение завершается ошибкой. А когда формирую слой динамически оно работает.

```
LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

linLayout.addView(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом варианте поставь строку  **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**  самой первой и все будет работать. Нельзя искать вьюху там, где ты еще ее даже не установил в качестве контента

Comment: Большое спасибо. Все получилось.